# Nokogiri XML to node

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm reading a local HTML document with Nokogiri like so:

```
f = File.open(local_xml)
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(f)
f.close
```

`@doc` contains a Nokogiri XML object that I can parse using `at_css`.

I want to modify it using Nokogiri's [XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html), and I'm absolutely stuck. How do I take this Nokogiri XML document and work with it using node methods?

For example:

```
@doc.at_css('rates tr').add_next_sibling(element)
```

returns:

```
undefined method `add_next_sibling' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

despite the fact that `@doc.class` is `Nokogiri::XML::Document`.

For completeness, here is the markup I'm trying to edit.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Exchange Rates</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="rates">
        <tr>
            <td class="up"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Saturday, Jan 12</td>
            <td class="rate up">3.83</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="up"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Friday, Jan 11</td>
            <td class="rate up">3.70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="down"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Thursday, Jan 10</td>
            <td class="rate down">3.68</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="down"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Wedensday, Jan 9</td>
            <td class="rate down">3.70</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="up"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Tuesday, Jan 8</td>
            <td class="rate up">3.66</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not provide a link to the HTML you are parsing but instead, embed it into your question. Without it, WHEN the link breaks, your question will become largely useless to future searchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load as HTML instead of XML `Nokogiri::HTML(f)`

Not getting in much detail on how Nokogiri works, lets say that XML does not have css right? So the method at_css doesn't make sense (maybe it does I dunno). So it should work loading as Html.

### Update

Just noticed one thing. You want to do `at_css('.rates tr')` insteand of `at_css('rates tr')` because that's how you select a class in css. Maybe it works with XML now.

Comment: Using CSS accessors with HTML and XML with Nokogiri makes perfect sense, depending on what you are trying to do. It's all about finding a path to the node or nodes desired, and CSS expresses that more clearly many times. Whether you are parsing XML or HTML isn't the issue, nor is it important when deciding whether to use CSS or XPath.

Comment: @theTinMan Ok thanks, but does class css selectors works the same?

Comment: Work the same in what way? They access nodes the same, they use different syntax to do so. CSS uses CSS accessors like we'd use with a stylesheet and avoid a lot of line noise that creeps into XPath accessors often.

Comment: So you can use at_css in a XML document as you can with a HTML document. I mean, can I do both in XML and HTML this for `<p class="bar foo">Lipsum</p>`. `@doc.at_css('p.foo')` Will it work the same way beeing `@doc` an XML or HTML nokogiri document?

Comment: Ok, I've just done some testing and seems it works both with XML and HTML

Comment: @ezuk, "`at_css('.rates tr')` will return an array" will NOT return an array (actually a `NodeSet`). Instead it will return a single `Node`. This is important to understand because getting it wrong is the source of all sorts of errors and questions about how to do anything with Nokogiri. That makes `at_css('.rates tr').first` wrong, which will cause any code written using this answer to fail.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example how to do what you are trying to do. Starting with `f` containing a shortened version of the HTML you want to parse:

```
require 'nokogiri'

f = '
<html>
<head>
<title>Exchange Rates</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="rates">
        <tr>
            <td class="up"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Saturday, Jan 12</td>
            <td class="rate up">3.83</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(f)
doc.at('.rates tr').add_next_sibling('<p>foobar</p>')

puts doc.to_html
```

Your code is incorrectly trying to find the `class="rates"` parameter for `<table>`. In CSS we'd use `.rates`. An alternate way to do it using CSS is `table[class="rates"]`.

Your example didn't define the node you were trying to add to the HTML, so I appended `<p>foobar</p>`. Nokogiri will let you build a node from scratch and append it, or use markup and add that, or you could find a node from one place in the HTML, remove it, and then insert it somewhere else.

That code outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Exchange Rates</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <table class="rates">
<tr>
<td class="up"><div></div></td>
            <td class="date">Saturday, Jan 12</td>
            <td class="rate up">3.83</td>
        </tr>
<p>foobar</p>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not necessary to use `at_css` or `at_xpath` instead of `at`. Nokogiri senses what type of accessor you're using and handles it. The same applies using `xpath` or `css` instead of `search`. Also, `at` is equivalent to `search('some accessor').first`, so it finds the first occurrence of the matching node.